# Как обозначить цифры в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text=(int), state=FSMAdmin.krasava1)
async def cm_start(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.reply('Твоя батарейка заряжена на 20%')
    await FSMAdmin.next()
```

Есть такой хэндлэр. Здесь надо указать чтобы он реагировал на цифру text=(int)#неправильно
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

При использовании FSM можно валидировать входные параметры. [Пример](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html):

```
# Check age. Age gotta be digit
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age_invalid(message: types.Message):
    """
    If age is invalid
    """
    return await message.reply("Age gotta be a number.\nHow old are you? (digits only)")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Update state and data
    await Form.next()
    await state.update_data(age=int(message.text))
    # Configure ReplyKeyboardMarkup
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Male", "Female")
    markup.add("Other")

    await message.reply("What is your gender?", reply_markup=markup)
```